# How to discard question draft

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Earlier, when asking new question there was *immediately available* "Discard" option.

I could discard question right away if I change my mind. This happens frequently: while preparing MCVE I often find an answer myself.

Now there is no such button. In the new UI I have to refresh page (or close tab and click "Ask question" button again) then I see draft and there is "Discard draft".

Why "Discard draft" is not shown initially?

Comment: I can't see it working like this in meta either. There is no "discard" link until I go back to the "ask a question" screen. https://imgur.com/a/YLt5MPR

Comment: Only after I go back to the question screen I get the ability to discard the draft. https://imgur.com/a/jJ4X5AX. I do not think this has been caused by the new ask a question interface. And IMO, it is fine as it is.

Comment: Your question stub probably just hasn't been cached yet.

Comment: @yivi, you are right, it's not working on meta "as before". I was probably revisiting page somehow (sometimes having 50+ tab opened at work). Will edit question.

Comment: @yivi, I am still quite sure what "discard" option was before availalble immediately without need to leave/refresh page. Would be nice is someone would confirm it though.

Comment: @yivi, *"it is fine as it is"* - well, hitting F5 is not a big problem, wasn't sure if I am reporting bug or asking for feature. If latter - yeah, ignore it.